# Could you please recommend a source to learn Inner Functions and Blaschke product?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I am looking for self study inner functions and Blaschke product from the scratch, yet I could not find any beginner friendly resource out there. It would be much appreciated if you could recommend me a source.